# Socket error 0x80004005: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. while programming in vb.net

Tags: sockets, udp, vb.net-2010, ethernet, arduino-ide

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino using an ethernet wired connection. I did that using python and C but now m getting difficulty doing the same with VB.net. Simply I am trying to send a UDP packet to Arduino using its IP address and port number and want the response to get back and show it in the textbox.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Environment, System.Text.Encoding


Public Class udpWindow
 Dim localIP As String = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList(0).ToString
 Dim localPort As Integer = 5000

 Dim publisher As New Sockets.UdpClient(0)
 Dim subscriber As New Sockets.UdpClient(localPort)

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    LocalIP_txt.Text = localIP
    localPort_txt.Text = localPort

 End Sub


 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
    publisher.Connect(ServerIP.Text, ServerPort.Text)
    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = ASCII.GetBytes("0")
    publisher.Send(sendbytes, sendbytes.Length)

 End Sub

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    subscriber.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 100
    subscriber.Client.Blocking = False
 End Sub


 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try

        Dim ep As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(0, localPort)
        Dim recvbytes() As Byte = subscriber.Receive(ep)
        'MsgBox("msg recieved")
        rcvMsgs.Text = ASCII.GetString(recvbytes)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

 End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone help me with a better alternative or with the correction?
Thanx in advance as this is my first query over here so pardon for any improper mistake.

Comment: You are putting `subscriber`'s socket into **non-blocking** mode. The `Receive()` method does not work in non-blocking mode. The error you are getting is basically telling you that the socket returned a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error when there is no data available to read. Use the [`BeginReceive()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive) or [`ReceiveAsync()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receiveasync) method instead for non-blocking reads, and let the socket notify you when data is available, don't poll for it

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to keep polling, then just get rid of the non-blocking mode, and check `subscriber.Available > 0` before calling `subscriber.Receive()`. Or, since you are using a timeout anyway, just have your `try..catch` ignore any `SocketException` whose `ErrorCode` is `WSAETIMEDOUT` (10060). Or, get rid of the timer and use a separate thread that calls `Receive()` in a loop without a timeout.

Comment: @RemyLebeau really wants to thank you for ur support. This was my first query on StackOverflow and got that sorted within a day m happy with my experience.